# How to debug released build with in-app billing functionality?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

Is it possible to test product subscription in debuggable mode of released apk?

I have updated the apk to alpha channel and want to test subscription purchase flow, but when I generate released build with debuggable : true in-app billing api generate error "The item you requested is not available for purchase."

How can I debug released build with in-app functionality?